# Conditional probability generating function - Binomial

Tags: probability, generating-functions, binomial-distribution

I'm working on the following problem:

> Y = $X{_1}+X{_2}+X{_3}+...+X{_N}$
>
> $N\overset{d}{\sim}Bi(n,p) $ and $X_i\overset{d}{\sim}Bi(m,q)$
>
> $N, X_1, X_2 $ are independent
>
> > $a)$ Find $P_{Y|N}$(z) and state values of $z$ for which it is defined
> >
> > $b)$ Find $P_{Y}(z)$ and state values of $z$ for which it is defined
> >
> > $c)$ Using $P_{Y}(z)$, evaluate  $E(Y)$

I am having difficulty with part $a)$ and I believe it's because I can't understand how $Y|N$ is distributed, or is this not relevant?

Comment: I think (I'm guessing) that you mean you don't understand the distribution of $Y|N$. For example if I tell you that $N = 1$, what is the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: I would say binomial, since $Y=X_1$

Comment: Binomial what? Then what about $N = 2$, and then generalize to $N = n$?

Comment: **Hint:** $Y$ is the sum of $N$ independent random variables, each the count of successes in $m$ iid Bernoulli trials with success rate $q$. So, therefore $Y$ is the count of ... *what* ?

Comment: I was considering a binomial, $(Y|N)∼Bi(nm,q)$ but I'm not entirely confident in the parameters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $Y$ is the sum of $N$ independent random variables, each the count of successes in $m$ iid Bernoulli trials with success rate $q$. So, therefore $Y$ is the count of ... *what*  ?   What distribution does this have?

Once you have identified the name of this distribution, you should know what is the probability generating function $\Pi_{Y\mid N}(z)$ and where $z$ is defined.

$$\Pi_{Y\mid N}(z) ~=~ (1-q+qz)^{Nm}$$

Then use $\Pi_Y(z) = \mathsf E(\Pi_{Y\mid N}(z))$

Finally $\mathsf E(Y) = \Pi_Y'(1)$

---

PS: Although you were asked to do it the hard way, the easy way is: $$\mathsf E(Y) =\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid N)) = \mathsf E(qNm) = qpnm$$

Comment: So I have used $(Y|N=i) ∼ Bi(im, q)$ and found that 
$P_{Y|N}(z) = (1-q+qz)^{im}$ 
Using this, $P_Y(z) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n ({1-q+q^{im}}){P(N=i)}$ where $P(N=i)$ is the binomial pmf... 
am I on the right track? I can't see this sum simplifying very much.

Comment: @Stephf97 Yes.  Note that we can also write: $\Pi_Y(z) =\mathsf E(\mathsf E(z^Y\mid N)) = \mathsf E(\Pi_{Y\mid N}(z))$ which, on reflection, might make the result easier to find.